# Survival analysis with time varying covariates using coxph in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

This is a snapshot of the R data frame `df1` that I have.

```
NEW_UPC         IRI_KEY     WEEK     UNITS     DOLLARS     F     D     PR
11820005991     1073521     1230     1         14.29      NONE   0     0
11820005991     1073521     1232     1         14.29      NONE   0     0
11820005991     1073521     1235     1         14.29      NONE   0     0
11820005991     1073521     1239     1         14.29      NONE   0     0
11820005991     1073521     1241     3         42.97      NONE   0     0
11820005991     1073521     1243     1         14.29      NONE   0     0
11820005991     1073521     1244     5         71.45      NONE   0     0
-----------     -------     ----     -         -----      ----   -     -
11820005991     1073525     1218     2         27.98      NONE   0     0
11820005991     1073525     1224     1         13.99      NONE   0     0
11820005991     1073525     1229     1         12.99      NONE   0     1
11820005991     1073525     1236     1         12.99      NONE   0     0
-----------     -------     ----     -         -----      ----   -     -
```

I am trying to fit a Cox proportional hazards model on a "subject-location-period" format data. I call this subject-location-period format because the `NEW_UPC` refers to a product ID, `IRI_KEY` refers to a store location, and `WEEK` refers to a week. The variables `UNITS`, `DOLLARS`, `F`, `D` and `PR` are time-varying and so I would like to use the Cox model with time-varying covariates. The references - [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221730/determine-if-a-time-dependent-cox-model-is-appropriate) and [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) - that I have looked up don't seem to have a data scenario similar to mine. Most resources talk about converting one line of subject observation into multiple lines of subject-period observations using `survsplit` or `tmerge`. My data is already in the subject-location-period format, so I don't have to do those operations. But my data does not have the `start`, `stop` and `event` variables that are used in the `coxph` formula. which goes like `coxph(Surv(start,stop,event)) ~ DOLLARS + F + D + PR`. I think I need to insert three new columns to create the `start`,`stop` and `event` variables. The event I am interested in my data is death of the product.

As a first step, for each `NEW_UPC`, I was able to identify the number of periods of existence using:

```
df1 %>% group_by(NEW_UPC,IRI_KEY) %>% summarise(Periods = n_distinct(WEEK))
```

I use the above approach, because please note that there are some missing periods without data. For e.g., for the product NEW_UPC value 11820005991, I don't have variable information for weeks 1231,1233,1234,1236,1237,1238,etc. So I cannot use `max(WEEK) - min(WEEK)` to find the number of periods for each product.

From hereon, I am just struggling how to proceed. Any ideas?

Added: Expected output

```
NEW_UPC     IRI_KEY UNITS  start  stop  event DOLLARS F    D PR
11820005991 1073521  1     1230  1232   0     14.29   NONE 0 0
11820005991 1073521  1     1232  1235   0     14.29   NONE 0 0
11820005991 1073521  1     1235  1239   0     14.29   NONE 0 0
----------- -------  -     ----  ----   -     -----   ---- - -
11820005991 1073521  2     1287  1291   1     27.98   NONE 0 0
11820005991 1073525  2     1218  1224   0     27.98   NONE 0 0
11820005991 1073525  1     1224  1229   0     13.99   NONE 0 0
11820005991 1073525  1     1229  1236   0     12.99   NONE 0 1
----------- -------  -     ----  ----   -     -----   ---- - -
11820005991 1073525  1     1297  1303   1     13.99   NONE 0 0
----------- -------  -     ----  ----   -     -----   ---- - -
```

...so on

Also, to identify censoring, if a product survives till week 1426 then it is censored.

Comment: To use survival analysis you do need some sort of event. I don’t see any in your data. Close vote for lack of clarity.

Comment: @42- Exactly. I need to create column of event using the information available. The event is exit/death of product, as I mentioned in my question. The last week that has a value of UNITS or DOLLARS will mark the event occurrence. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Can you provide a couple lines of what the intended output is? You can arrange the data so that the start and end week of each product appears in one line, but then how to do you want to the other variables to be treated?

Comment: Have made any efforts at coding? Can you post code and input data to construct R-object.